# AttributeError: 'Server' object has no attribute 'setsockopt'

Tags: python, sockets, module, server

I wanted to make a Multiplayer Game with Python and used PodSixNet for it. But if I run my Server, it displays this:

```
AttributeError: 'Server' object has no attribute 'setsockopt'
```

And here is the PodSixNet-Code:

```
import socket
import sys

from .async import poll, asyncore
from .Channel import Channel

class Server(asyncore.dispatcher):
    channelClass = Channel

    def __init__(self, channelClass=None, localaddr=("127.0.0.1", 31425), listeners=5):
        if channelClass:
            self.channelClass = channelClass
        self._map = {}
        self.channels = []
        asyncore.dispatcher.__init__(self, map=self._map)
        self.create_socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        self.setsockopt(socket.IPPROTO_TCP, socket.TCP_NODELAY, 1) 
        self.set_reuse_addr()
        self.bind(localaddr)
        self.listen(listeners)

    def handle_accept(self):
        try:
            conn, addr = self.accept()
        except socket.error:
            print('warning: server accept() threw an exception')
            return
        except TypeError:
            print('warning: server accept() threw EWOULDBLOCK')
            return

        self.channels.append(self.channelClass(conn, addr, self, self._map))
        self.channels[-1].Send({"action": "connected"})
        if hasattr(self, "Connected"):
            self.Connected(self.channels[-1], addr)

    def Pump(self):
        [c.Pump() for c in self.channels]
        poll(map=self._map)

#########################
#   Test stub   #
#########################

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import unittest

    class ServerTestCase(unittest.TestCase):
        testdata = {"action": "hello", "data": {"a": 321, "b": [2, 3, 4], "c": ["afw", "wafF", "aa", "weEEW", "w234r"], "d": ["x"] * 256}}
        def setUp(self):
            print("ServerTestCase")
            print("--------------")

            class ServerChannel(Channel):
                def Network_hello(self, data):
                    print("*Server* ran test method for 'hello' action")
                    print("*Server* received:", data)
                    self._server.received = data

            class EndPointChannel(Channel):
                connected = False
                def Connected(self):
                    print("*EndPoint* Connected()")

                def Network_connected(self, data):
                    self.connected = True
                    print("*EndPoint* Network_connected(", data, ")")
                    print("*EndPoint* initiating send")
                    self.Send(ServerTestCase.testdata)

            class TestServer(Server):
                connected = False
                received = None
                def Connected(self, channel, addr):
                    self.connected = True
                    print("*Server* Connected() ", channel, "connected on", addr)

            self.server = TestServer(channelClass=ServerChannel)

            sender = asyncore.dispatcher(map=self.server._map)
            sender.create_socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
            sender.connect(("localhost", 31425))
            self.outgoing = EndPointChannel(sender, map=self.server._map)

        def runTest(self):
            from time import sleep
            print("*** polling for half a second")
            for x in range(250):
                self.server.Pump()
                self.outgoing.Pump()
                if self.server.received:
                    self.assertTrue(self.server.received == self.testdata)
                    self.server.received = None
                sleep(0.001)
            self.assertTrue(self.server.connected == True, "Server is not connected")
            self.assertTrue(self.outgoing.connected == True, "Outgoing socket is not connected")

        def tearDown(self):
            pass
            del self.server
            del self.outgoing

    unittest.main()
```

And here is my Server code:

```
import PodSixNet.Channel
import PodSixNet.Server
from time import sleep
class ClientChannel(PodSixNet.Channel.Channel):
    def Network(self, data):
        print (data)

class Server(PodSixNet.Server.Server):

    channelClass = ClientChannel

    def Connected(self, channel, addr):
        print ("new connection:", channel)

print ("STARTING SERVER ON LOCALHOST")
gameServer=Server()
while True:
    gameServer.Pump()
    sleep(0.01)
```

I am really confused because im a beginner in python.
Thanks for any help